# Discord python bot background text colour

Tags: discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

I wrote a discord role selection menu like following:

````
class Whoyouare_select(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self):
        options=[
        discord.SelectOption(label = "Developer", emoji="<:developer:1085656157764464854>"),
        discord.SelectOption(label = "Quant", emoji=""),
        discord.SelectOption(label = "Enthusiast", emoji="‍")
        ]
    
        super().__init__(placeholder = "Pick a role...",  options=options)

    async def callback(self, interaction = discord.Interaction):
        user = interaction.user
        guild = interaction.guild
        
        role = guild.get_role(role_map[self.values[0]])
        
        embed = discord.Embed(title = f"```ansiAdded role(s): \u001b[0;37;42m@{self.values[0]}```")
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed, ephemeral=True)
````

`role_map` is a dict containing key and value pairs for my discord server roles. I would like to send an embed message upon selection of the roles like below:

[image]

but i am only able to get this:

[image]

i dont think what i want to achieve is an actual mention therefore i tried to alter the text background but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i dont think what i want to achieve is an actual mention

Yes it is. The first screenshot is quite literally an actual mention.

You can't change the background colour. Discord *does* support ANSII codes for codeblocks, but that won't fly here.

To create a mention string for a role, you can just use `Role.mention`.

```py
...Embed(title = f"Added role(s): {self.values[0].mention}")
```

Though embed titles don't support mentions, so you'll have to do it somewhere else (e.g. a field, the description, ...)

Comment: got it thanks. but theres two things worth noting tho. 1. self.values[0] is a string so I used role.mention. 2. the Role.mention attribute returns a string and if i embed this in the response it woudn't actually mention the role members but it looks like the memtion, which is what i was trying to get.

Comment: @KevinLi As I said in my answer, embed titles don't support mentions so you have to do it somewhere else. The second point you're making is just telling me what I've already told you in my answer. It won't actually mention the members but it just "looks like" the mention, **because this isn't supported in titles**. The screenshot you included is just bold text (markdown) in a description, not a title.